# Cannot understand how my book is counting algorithm steps

Tags: java, sorting

In this example my book shows me how to count the steps in a bubble sorting algorithm. Each comment in the code explains why the amount added to `steps` is added.

Code:

```
public void bubbleSort(ArrayList <Comparable> list){
   steps = 0;
   for (int outer = 0; outer < list.size() - 1; outer++){
     for (int inner = 0; inner < list.size()-outer-1; inner++){
         steps += 3;//count one compare and 2 gets
         if (list.get(inner).compareTo(list.get(inner + 1)) > 0){
            steps += 4;//count 2 gets and 2 sets
            Comparable temp = list.get(inner);
            list.set(inner,list.get(inner + 1));
            list.set(inner + 1,temp);
         }
     }
   }
 }
```

When looking at `steps += 4;` I understand why they add `4`: simply because there's 2 get statements and 2 set statements. However in this step `steps += 3;//count one compare and 2 gets` I don't see why it's adding 3. Where in the code before the `if` statement is there a compare statement? Furthermore where are the "2 gets" before the `if` statement? Maybe I am misunderstanding the way they count the steps but this is literally all my book provided.

Comment: Maybe the list.size()x2 are your 2 gets and the comparison is inner < list.size()-outer-1

Comment: Well, then the `list.size()` in the outer for would be counted, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two gets and one compare inside of the if statement itself:

```
if (list.get(inner).compareTo(list.get(inner + 1)) > 0)
```